# Is there any function to retrieve temporary folder or path from matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm searching any function to retrieve temporary folder (C:\Windows\Temp). Is there any function to do this from Matlab?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `tempdir`:

```
tempDirName = tempdir;
```

Comment: I've try that, but is not that the result that I expected. I want exactly the temporary folder of the system (for example, in windows C:\windows\temp). Thanks anyway!

Comment: I just checked - tempdir asks windows (for environment variable TEMP) - and the directory is specified under "system properties"-"advanced"-"environment variables" - you can set it there to your liking.

Comment: @bdecaf if you ship your m-files to other systems (non-Windows, or older versions) then you want to be sure that the correct path is returned, `tempdir` does that for you.

Comment: I think we miss each other - I just wanted to point out how (s)he needs to configure windows so `tempdir` will return what (s)he wants. 
I suppose in other systems (s)he wouldn't require the temp path to be under "c:\windows\temp"

Comment: Of course, I want to port my m-files to other systems later, then tempdir will return the correct path. My mistake was to think that "C:\Windows\temp" is the temp folder under Windows 7, but it is another folder.

Comment: You probably shouldn't change %TEMP% in the OS - it needs to be a per-profile or per-session directory. If you change that (e.g. to `C:\Windows\Temp`), it could break other programs that use it and rely on its normal semantics. If you need a different location for your files, you may want to write your own custom alternative to `tempdir`.